# What does grep -w do?

Tags: grep, man, options, documentation

In [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Frequently_asked_questions#64-bit) grep is used with the option `-w`. I did `man grep` and `grep --help` to try to find what the aforementioned option does. Neither output says anything about a `-w` option.

What does that option do? Why does it not appear in `man`or `--help`? In case something similar happens again, where else can I check for an answer?

I am currently using Ubuntu, if that is relevant (is it?)

Comment: My man page and `--help` (from Debian, probably older than yours) both list `-w, --word-regexp         force PATTERN to match only whole words`. Which `grep` version are you using?

Comment: And/or Ubuntu version...?

Comment: If on a GNU system, try `info -- grep -w` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
# grep --help | grep -e -w
  -w, --word-regexp         force PATTERN to match only whole words
  -H, --with-filename       print file name with output lines
  -L, --files-without-match  print only names of FILEs with no selected lines
  -l, --files-with-matches  print only names of FILEs with selected lines
# grep PRETTY /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04 LTS"
# man grep | grep -e -w -A1
       -w, --word-regexp
              Select only those lines containing matches that form whole words.  The test is that the matching substring must either be at the beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent  character.   Similarly,  it
              must be either at the end of the line or followed by a non-word constituent character.  Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.
```

Answer (score 2):

> -w, --word-regexp
>       Select only those lines containing matches that form whole words. The test is that the matching substring must either be at the
>   beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent
>   character. Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or
>   followed by a non-word constituent character. Word-constituent
>   characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.

Source: https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep